# Can the cache folder in android application sandbox be cleared automatically by OS?

Tags: android, android-storage

I searched in the Android documentation and didn't find the fact that Android OS may clear applications cache if there is no available storage within the device, what do you think? Is there such strategy in Android OS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `getCacheDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()):

> The system will automatically delete files in this directory as disk space is needed elsewhere on the device.

So, yes, Android will delete cache files.

Comment: Also there is an option on application settings to clear the cache